# Configurable Product Option that doesn't exist

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I have configurable products that have multiple simple products associated with it. Some of these simple products do not have the same options for others within this config.

For instance:
Configurable Product:

- Simple Product A - Size: Large, Color: Black
- Simple Product B - Size:
  Medium, Color: Red

You can see that there is no product that is Large AND Red but the configurable product allows this selection. It even allows the user to add to cart, proceeds to checkout and lists that product as one of the other product (Simple Product A).

How can I fix this issue?

I have created Simple Product C - Size: Large, Color: Red Quantity 0 (Out of stock). Nothing happens, in fact the availability still indicates In Stock.

It simply does not read the configurable product options properly.

For reference, this is the page that has this problem: [LINK](http://69.72.252.178/~davidsfi/index.php/bedding-285/sheets-sets/st-pierre-850tc-sheet-set.html)

Product Options White + King is there but set to quantity 0 out of stock. It should not allow to be selected.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I am using the SCP Simple Configurable Product Module

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix this, I installed the [Easylife extension](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.fr/2013/10/easylife-switcher-extension.html)
and set to hide configurable options that are out of stock!